# The app references non-public selectors in Payload/ (App ID) : number, setNumber:

Tags: xcode, app-store, xcode-organizer, non-public-selectors

I'm trying to load the app, but it gives me this warning:

> The app references non-public selectors in Payload/ (App ID) : number, setNumber:

In the app there are GAI and AAShareBubbles Frameworks.

Comment: Same here, also using GAI (3.0.8). Their changelogs show "Fixed an issue so GTM users can use NSNumber for ecommerce data" (3.0.7, May 2014), which may be triggering this. We may have to wait for GAI 3.0.9, or hope that Apple will let it slide.

Comment: Thanks, but regarding the approval on the App Store, there are problems??

Edit: The app was approved today successfully!!!

Comment: My app (Frax) was approved yesterday successfully as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just got this on 9/11/14 using Xcode6 GM and OSX 10.10. Xcode said the app was not submitted. However I went to itunes connect about 15 minutes later and the binary was in the build section (on the new iTC webpage). Added the build and submitted to Apple. Waiting for Review now!

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: Is this gonna be fixed someday? Because everytime i upload a build this happen, the build is up but in xcode there is no accepted message like submitted with validation warnings, this only happen with xcode 6.

Answer (score 2):

When I was uploading my binary from xcode 6.0.1 it shows me error,But Again I tried to upload binary from application loader It successfully adding application with Warning of "references non-public selectors in payload number" Just avoid Go to Next.So after few minutes Application status was "Waiting for review"
However as per my point of view,It is better to do upload binary from application loader latest.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a warning. I guess, it's just to let developer know what non-public selectors app is referencing, before submitting for review.